# How to know whether a molecule is 'stabilized'

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

According to a reference book, in acid-base reactions, the position of equilibrium is shifted towards when the conjugate base is more 'stable' and the relative stabilities are compared by

1. different atoms
2. resonance
3. induction
4. orbital

What I don't understand is that in the first 3 of criteria. They are about how able for the electrons to move around (delocalize). But in the fourth criteria, presence of triple bonds make the molecule most stable since the electrons are confined in a small place (stronger attraction to the nucleus). Doesn't this mean electrons are 'localized' instead of 'delocalized' (i.e. less stable)? Do I get it wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you refer to a source without naming it.